# How can I store two values for one key with Replit Database

Tags: python, replit-database

I'm using CoingGecko API for acquiring info about crypto. I have a function for getting a json from the API of crypto currencies. Then I upload the id of crypto and its current price to a Replit database (id becomes the key and the current price a value of that key). I want to have a second value for that key which would be a 24h change in percentage of crypto price. Is it possible to have another value for a key? If not, how the should I approach my problem.

The function:

```
def getCryptoPrices(crypto):
  URL = 'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=eur'
  r = requests.get(url = URL)
  data = r.json()

  #putting cryptocurrencies with their prices to a database
  for i in range(len(data)):
    db[data[i]['id']] = data[i]['current_price']
  if crypto in db.keys():
    return db[crypto]
  else:
    return None
```

Comment: convert the pre-existiing value to list, and append it. Or else, better store it as a list initially...

Comment: @GhostOps Will do that, thank you for your help!